spring boot runnable jar cant connect to database returns DataSource: 'url' error
I am building my own hobby project in spring boot and wanted to export the project as a runnable jar file. For this project and jre I use java 17
In Eclipse the application works without errors and I can connect to the database without issues, but when I export the application as a runnable jarfile it does not work and I get error below.
>>java -jar Runnable_tracker.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.3)

2024-05-05T23:59:53.729+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] c.e.T.TopicArchiverApplication           : Starting TopicArchiverApplication using Java 17.0.2 with PID 30180 (C:\Users\johan\eclipse-workspace\Topic_archiver\Runnable_tracker.jar started by johan in C:\Users\johan\eclipse-workspace\Topic_archiver)
2024-05-05T23:59:53.732+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] c.e.T.TopicArchiverApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-05-05T23:59:54.277+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-05-05T23:59:54.326+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 38 ms. Found 3 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-05-05T23:59:54.790+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-05-05T23:59:54.800+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-05-05T23:59:54.801+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-05-05T23:59:54.842+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-05-05T23:59:54.844+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1075 ms
2024-05-05T23:59:54.892+02:00  WARN 30180 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception with message: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2024-05-05T23:59:54.895+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2024-05-05T23:59:54.910+02:00  INFO 30180 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-05-05T23:59:54.926+02:00 ERROR 30180 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
        If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
        If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

My application.properity file looks fine as it shows below and these "parameter nameings works"
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/topicusers
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=Galaxy2022
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properites.hibernate.format_sql=true

logging.level.org.springframework.web: DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
logging.level.org.hibernate: ERROR
spring.mvc.log-request-details=true

spring.main.web-application-type= SERVLET

server.error.include-message=always
#disabling security to test posting

I know that sometimes when you run a Springboot application in eclipse not all configuration are reed correctly, something to do with spring to read halv the configuration at a time (If I remember correctly) and these configuration stay until one restart eclipse or pc.
The issue is that the configuration work inside eclipse, when I run the application, but not when running the jar file.


Can you please take a look at the following article: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-failed-to-configure-data-source. Hope that it is going to help you!

How do you create the runnable jar? Your sentence " when I export the application as a runnable jarfile it does not work" has me worried that you aren't using the Spring Boot plugin to make the runnable jar but have some other means (which you shouldn't have/do).

It's probable that your JAR app doesn't have the JDBC driver included. You can easily check and manage dependencies using tools like Maven or Gradle, which I'd recommend if you're not already using one of them!

@M.Deinum I use exlipse to export a running jar. I did that 6 years ago to a maven project and it worked fine (exported a rest server as a running jar).
I don´t know how to use springboot plugin. I will take a look.

@OussamaEL I have the jdcb included in a seperate folder while exporting the running jar. I will include the folder in my question.

Can someone reslove this question.
I just noticed that I forgot to update.
There are no issue here, problem was when I tried to build a normal jar file with exlipse. same issue when I tried to build a fat jar and used the maven commands clean install.
Using the maven command package resolved the issue.

Using the maven command package resolved the issue in my case.
The problem was that I tried to build a normal jar file with Eclipse.
Two issues occured, when I tried to build a fat jar and used the maven commands clean install.

This would be better as a comment.
